# How to extract changeable text from text by using BS4?

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I want to get a number between "/" and "]" from tag below.

For this case, it would be 43.
Number's digit is variable.

```
<p class="page_info">
    [1/43] [total 4,264]
</p>
```

Answer (score 0):

Without using `regex` you can use the following line of code:

```
soup.select_one('p.page_info').get_text(strip=True).split()[0].strip('[]').split('/')[1]
```